# Adding decode instances to a class that can recall the main class

Tags: c++

i try to design an Infrared receive and sending library for different protocols. The main focus should be speed&compact, so i do not want to decode every protocol, only the selected.

So the idea is that the user can select the protocols that should be decoded. At the moment i solve it like this, that i have different protocol classes which are all inheriting from a main protocol class with defined virtual functions. This pointer is passed to the function.

```
IRLprotocolNEC IRprotocol;
IRLremote.begin(interruptIR, IRprotocol);

void CIRLremote::interruptIR(void){
// for no user function set we need to pause IR
// to not overwrite the actual values until they are read.
if (newInput) return; //  || pauseIR

//save the duration between the last reading
unsigned long time = micros();
unsigned long duration = time - mLastTime;
mLastTime = time;

// check if we have a new input and call the userfunction
// if no userfunction is set, flag a newinput signal and block
if (IRprotocol->decodeIR(duration)){
    if (user_onReceive != NULL)
        user_onReceive(IRprotocol->IRData);
    else
        newInput = true;
}
```

}

Now i ran into a problem that the main class (CIRLremote) is providing basic decoding functions (not the one listed above) but with different timings to input (for Nec the timings are shorter than for Panasonic). So i somehow need to access the main class from the protocol class. Otherwise i have to double everything.

I could hardcode every protocol and use #define for deselecting each protocol but this is not the way i want to do this. Is there any smart way i could solve this?

Same for sending: I have a basic function that calls the sending function 1-3 times depending on the protocol and also disables interrupts.

The current project status can be found here:
https://github.com/NicoHood/IRLremote/tree/0525435b86ee6202bceaee11e8b7ddded871042f

Comment: Construct the protocol object with a pointer to an interface providing the basic decoding functions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Answer (score 0):

Make a definition of pure virtual function `timings`, returning a const reference to struct containing timings. Implement this function in each of derived classes.

**Alternatively**, change decoding function into function's template. In each of derived classes, make a variables containing timings, and use them in decoding function.

**Hint**: if timings of each protocol are constant, declare timing struct or timing variables
as `static constexpr`.

Comment: I added the whole source above. Not sure if this could work, seems complicated. I want to keep the flash low, that it doesnt compile everything and also doesnt use a lot of overhead. And what about sending? For some sending functions i need to call different PWM functions. I only implemented one writing function yet. But i cannot just return something like the kHz value. I dont want to compile all kHz sending functions.